# vertically center an overflow image

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to solve my issue with the solutions I have found online. The image simply won't move.

I am looking to center the image vertically in my div. So instead of it showing from the top down, it starts somewhere in the middle.

**HTML**

```
<article class="banner">
    <button class="button">Schedule your FREE assesment</button>
    <img class="mySlides" src="images/img1.jpg" width="100%">
    <img class="mySlides" src="images/img2.jpg" width="100%">
    <img class="mySlides" src="images/img3.jpg" width="100%">
    <img class="mySlides" src="images/img4.jpg" width="100%">
</article>
```

**CSS**

```
.banner {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #212121;
    height: 180px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: .80
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.button {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -14%; /* Anyway to make this centered more eficiently? */
    margin-top: 5%;
    border: 0;
    background-color: #C60505;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    font: Arial-Heavy;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000;
}
```

It is worth mentioning the class attached to the images is linked to JS that has a slideshow-like effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.button`  should have thse settins to center it (vertically and horizontally):

```
.button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

This moves `button`'s top left corner into the exact middle of its parent element (using `top` and `left` 50%) and then moves it back 50% left and up of its own width and height (using the `transorm` parameter), therefore centering it inside the parent element.

If you really only want vertical centering, use only `top: 50%;` and `transform: translateY(50%)`.

Comment: Ahh, that does help the button. Sorry I forgot I had the comment in there to remind myself of that issue later. This post was intended for the 4 image that slideshow in the div.

Comment: well, that should work for *any* child element of `.banner`

Comment: After adding and applying it to .mySlides it seems to have correctly centered it but now the image only spans half the parent width ways.

Comment: `.mySlides img {
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}`

Does not effect the positioning of the images.

Comment: 1.) you forgot `position: absolute`, 2.) the selector has to be `img.mySlides { ... }`